# Interpretation of functions `mktime()` and `ctime()`

Tags: c++, time

Consider the following code snippet whose functionality I hope it is explained through the comments:

```
string date = "11/01/2018"; // value of date is only for test
struct tm tm;
strptime(date.c_str(), "%d/%m/%Y", &tm); // convert date to tm struct
time_t ret = mktime(&tm); // now convert tm to time_t
```

Now, when I print out `date` and `ret` variables as follows:

```
cout << date << endl
       << ctime(&ret) << endl;
```

I get the following output:

```
11/01/2018
Sun Feb  3 23:44:56 2497
```

As someone could see, the date printed on the second line is not close to the date represented in the variable `date`.

Could someone please give me some clue about why this behaviour? I need absolute times in order to compare them easily, but of course, I must also manage them as string representations formatted to Europe style.

Comment: You should inspect what `tm` actually contains first, after the call to `strptime`, so that you know where the issue starts.

Comment: Thank you @PaulMcKenzie. I would say that `tm` fields should be filled according to the context (or absent of) of string `date`. In this case, the hours, minutes, seconds, etc are missing, but I would hope that `mktime()` sets them. Anyway, I am going to verify them.

Comment: [Cannot duplicate](https://www.ideone.com/DK7NdC)

Comment: I see the code works correctly on Ideone. However, I execute it here and It does not stop being surprising to me that I get wrong results. I am starting to suspect some misunderstanding on my part with localization. My time zone is at -4 UTC.

Comment: Solved @PaulMcKenzie. man page of `strptime()` says: "this function does not initialize tm but stores only the values specified. This  means that tm should be initialized before the call ...". Now I set `tm` through `memset()`, and everything works ok. Thanks to your suggestion I solved my problem. If you want, you can answer my question and I would be glad for voting and approving it.

Comment: Oh yes, forgot that for many C-structs, they do not initialize themselves unless they're global, so you wind up with junk within the struct if you use it.  Usage of C++ basically has made setting structs to the default unnecessary (if the struct / class is coded "nicely").